# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress

Tags: java, glassfish, elasticsearch, classnotfound

I am trying to use elasticsearch in my J2EE application but I am getting `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress` during deployment to Glassfish 3.1. IntelliJ shows no error during compilation.

I use maven with dependency in pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This happens when use this code in my project:

```
Client client = new TransportClient().addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("localhost", 9200));
```

I took look into elasticsearch-1.0.0.jar used by maven and found that TransportAddress is interface. Probably the whole library it not being put into glassfish.

Here is complete stacktrace:

```
[#|2014-02-18T15:05:00.963+0100|INFO|glassfish3.1.2|org.jboss.weld.ClassLoading|_ThreadID=51;_ThreadName=Thread-2;|catching
org.jboss.weld.resources.spi.ResourceLoadingException: Error loading class modules.core.service.CmsViewerServiceImpl
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:167)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.loadWeldClass(BeanDeployer.java:108)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClass(BeanDeployer.java:79)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployer.addClasses(BeanDeployer.java:123)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.BeanDeployment.createBeans(BeanDeployment.java:184)
    at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.WeldBootstrap.deployBeans(WeldBootstrap.java:350)
    at org.glassfish.weld.WeldDeployer.event(WeldDeployer.java:179)
    at org.glassfish.kernel.event.EventsImpl.send(EventsImpl.java:128)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.load(ApplicationInfo.java:277)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:460)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:389)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$1.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:348)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:363)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1085)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1200(CommandRunnerImpl.java:95)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1291)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1259)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:461)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.service(AdminAdapter.java:212)
    at com.sun.grizzly.tcp.http11.GrizzlyAdapter.service(GrizzlyAdapter.java:179)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.HK2Dispatcher.dispath(HK2Dispatcher.java:117)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$Hk2DispatcherCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:354)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:195)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.invokeAdapter(ProcessorTask.java:860)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.doProcess(ProcessorTask.java:757)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.ProcessorTask.process(ProcessorTask.java:1056)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.DefaultProtocolFilter.execute(DefaultProtocolFilter.java:229)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.executeProtocolFilter(DefaultProtocolChain.java:137)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:104)
    at com.sun.grizzly.DefaultProtocolChain.execute(DefaultProtocolChain.java:90)
    at com.sun.grizzly.http.HttpProtocolChain.execute(HttpProtocolChain.java:79)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ProtocolChainContextTask.doCall(ProtocolChainContextTask.java:54)
    at com.sun.grizzly.SelectionKeyContextTask.call(SelectionKeyContextTask.java:59)
    at com.sun.grizzly.ContextTask.run(ContextTask.java:71)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:532)
    at com.sun.grizzly.util.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:513)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/elasticsearch/common/transport/TransportAddress
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2317)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1762)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:105)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections$4.work(SecureReflections.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.run(SecureReflectionAccess.java:52)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflectionAccess.runAndWrap(SecureReflectionAccess.java:63)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.SecureReflections.getDeclaredFields(SecureReflections.java:102)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.<init>(WeldClassImpl.java:154)
    at org.jboss.weld.introspector.jlr.WeldClassImpl.of(WeldClassImpl.java:119)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:59)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer$TransformTypeToWeldClass.apply(ClassTransformer.java:50)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingValueReference.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:355)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.compute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:184)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingSegment.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:153)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap.getOrCompute(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:69)
    at com.google.common.collect.ComputingConcurrentHashMap$ComputingMapAdapter.get(ComputingConcurrentHashMap.java:393)
    at org.jboss.weld.resources.ClassTransformer.loadClass(ClassTransformer.java:163)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.elasticsearch.common.transport.TransportAddress
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClassData(ASURLClassLoader.java:808)
    at com.sun.enterprise.loader.ASURLClassLoader.findClass(ASURLClassLoader.java:696)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    ... 55 more
|#]
```

Is there something I am missing? Should I add elasticsearch library somehow manually to glassfish?

Thank you for suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have not mentioned in your pom to include the dependencies, those jars won't be where you run your code. You should either put dependencies in your target jar or manually put hem into the containers lib folder. Check out maven packaging.

Comment: You say its not enough to mention dependency on elasticsearch in `pom.xml`? I have to specify that maven has include it in the output war, right?

Comment: yes if you just mention it in pom, maven downloads it into your local maven repo and compiles. But you will need those dependencies where you run your app. If it is a web app then your container should supply it for you. So put them into the containers lib folder. Otherwise pack them all together.

Comment: You were right. I had to copy libs to `\glassfish\domains\domain1\lib\ext\`. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just add `<packaging>war</packaging>` to your pom.xml and everything will be fine.